# Close C# Console After Code Execution in MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, console-application

I'm writing a small program to take care of some automated plotting. I'm using a console application which simply runs through the code a finished by exporting a `pdf` file of the plot.

Since I'm in the testing phase, I need to run the program every time I want to see the effect of a change/addition. This means I get a lot of open console windows very fast, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Is it possible the close the console window programmatically?

I've tried `Environment.Exit()`, but it does not appear to do anything.

**Minimum example**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //Put any or no code here
}
```

I'd expect the console window to close upon completion of the Program.Main() method. Instead, the console asks for 'any key' input and does not close after a key is pressed.

**Console output:**

```
Press any key to continue...
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process Complete] (<- translated from danish)
```

Comment: Even if there is no code in the 'Main' method, it will wait for input. Hindrik's answer does make the console close when the process is completely finished, but it still asks for any key input after completing the program.

Comment: Did you try to run the program in both debug and release mode? Does it change in either of them? Did you use visual studio?

Answer (score 5):

This is a setting in the Terminal Preferences in macOS itself. 
Open Terminal -> Open Terminal context menu in the top left -> Select Preferences... -> Select your Terminal Profile -> Go to Shell tab -> Select "Close if the shell exited cleanly" in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Well, this makes it close the terminal window after the "Press any key to continue..." prompt. Thanks a lot. Do you happen to know if it's possible to skip that last prompt?

Comment: That is actually a setting of your project iirc. I can't remember where this was exactly, but it is somewhere in your .csproj file.

Comment: i am also curious about that setting. any clues?

Comment: Right click solution -> Properties -> Application -> Output type -> Windows Application.